# Use regex to replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I have around 1 thousand lines like the following that I need to amend:

```
RENAME TABLE my_tablename1 TO ;
```

I want to remove the my_ prefix and then insert the text after the word TO and its immediate space.

So the above example would become:

```
RENAME TABLE my_tablename1 TO tablename1;
```

Is this possible with regex?

I am working inside sublime if that makes a difference.

Comment: could you be more specific about what will be on each line

Comment: Well, ain't this awkward.

Answer (score 2):

The Sublime regex engine uses the perl syntax (http://boost.sourceforge.net/libs/regex/doc/format_perl_syntax.html).

In Sublime open the replace input box (`Find > Replace`):

Then, in the field "Find What:" (Don't forget to enable regex in the first icon) type:

```
my_(tablename1) TO
```

In the field "Replace with:" type:

```
$& $1
```